# web application audit task require my remote IP to be allowed on application network firewall

Tags: security, firewall, web-applications, attacks, vulnerability

I want to audit a web application which is hosted on a web server sitting behind a cyberoam firewall. My task is to run a scan from my remote machine which has ISP MTNL broadband. My machine gets a private IP address through DHCP and currently it has following configuration:

- Wireless adaptor: 192.168.1.7 (private)
- Gateway of my MTNL modem: 192.168.1.1

But when I do whatismyip, the result comes out to be the address of the default gateway router, which is set up at MTNL and looks like 59.178.x.x.

Now in order to audit web application, I want to allow my remote machine IP address on the cyberoam firewall . Please tell me which IP should be given to administrator to allow it at application network?

Comment: Give them your external IP.

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by external IP?

Comment: Is the default gateway router IP like 59.178.X.X?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, use the second IP Address (59.178.x.x) which is your Public address and is the source address of all the traffic leaving your local network.

Side note: you shouldn't need a hole in the firewall to perform penetration tests (if that is what you mean by "audit web app" -- the firewall forms part of your defences. You wouldn't disable it for a real attacker.

Comment: If I run nmap scan from my machine towards application then result shows a filtered ports which means that nmap request are getting dropped somewhere in between (probably at application firewall) so may be I need to allow my public IP at firewall?

Comment: For most I need to do vulnerability assessment of application sitting behind the firewall. Yes, I do agree with your suggestion that firewall forms part of defences but the major concern is to check the open ports on web server hosting web application.